# Send data to a webform using MS Access VBA

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I am trying to send data from an Access DB to a website http://www.lee.vote/voters/check-your-registration-status/.  I'm able to use similar code (below) to send data to a different website, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work for this website.

The HTML from what I'm trying to fill in:

```htm
<div id="FindVoterForm">
    <div id="IntroText">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 3px;">Voter Information in&nbsp;<span id="MainCounty">Lee</span>&nbsp;County</h1>
        <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">Sample Ballots and Voting Locations</h2>
    <span class="style1" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Complete the form to see:</span><ul style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <li class="style1"><b>Where to vote on election day</b></li>
        <li class="style1"><b>Sample ballots</b></li>
        <li class="style1"><b>Upcoming elections</b></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="style2" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        You'll also be able to:</p>
    <ul style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <li class="style2">Request a mail ballot</li>
            <li class="style2">Review/update your voter registration information</li>
            <li class="style2">Check the status of your mail ballot</li>
            <li class="style2">Review your voting activity for the past 12 months</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="NotRegistered" style="font-size: small;"><a href="https://www.voterfocus.com/ws/pfinder/printvapp4.php?county=lee" target="_blank">If you are not registered to vote please fill out our voter registration form</a></div><br>
    <i><b style="text-decoration: underline;">All items are required</b></i>.
    </div>
    <div class="voterForm">
    <div class="voterFormLine"><div>1.</div><div>Voter's Last Name</div><div><input title="Please enter your last name." id="NameID" type="text" size="10" maxlength="35" value=""></div> 
    </div><div class="voterFormLine"><div>2.</div><div>Voter's Birth Date</div><div><input title="Please enter your birth date (MM/DD/YYYY)." id="BirthDate" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
    <br>MM/DD/YYYY</div></div><div class="voterFormLine"><div>3.</div>
    <div><a title="House Number" href="https://www.voterfocus.com/VFVoterGlossery.php?term=House Number" target="_blank">House Number</a> of Voter's Residence Address</div>
    <div><input title="Please enter your house street number." id="StNumber" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value=""></div> 
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div><div style="text-align: center;"><h2 id="MoreVoter" style="display: none;"><b></b></h2>
    <button id="ButtonForm" onclick="ButtonForm_onclick()" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button></div>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

The VBA code:

```vb
'creates a new internet explorer window
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'opens Lee County registration check
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.lee.vote/voters/check-your-registration-status/"
End With

'waits until IE is loaded
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop

'sends data to the webpage
Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("NameID").setattribute("value", Last_Name)
Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("BirthDate").setattribute("value", Date_of_Birth.Value)
Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("StNumber").setattribute("value", Street_Number.Value)

'"clicks" the button to display the results
IE.Document.getelementbyid("ButtonForm").Click
```

Any help?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you do any interaction with the webpage or none at all?

Comment: Not this webpage.  I cannot pass the data (string variables) from Access to the form fields on the webpage.

Comment: Can you interact with the page at all? e.g. read data from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I came up with after the (much needed) help determining that I was not really navigating to the right webpage for the form:

```
'creates a new internet explorer window
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'opens Lee County registration check
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.electionsfl.org/VoterInfo/vflookup.html?county=lee"
End With

'waits until IE is loaded
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.busy
    DoEvents
Loop
x = Timer + 2
Do While Timer < x
    DoEvents
Loop

'sends data to the webpage
Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("NameID").setattribute("value", Last_Name.Value)
    'formats DOB to correct output
    Dim DOBMonth As Integer
    Dim DOBDay As Integer
    Dim DOBYear As Integer
    DOBMonth = Month(Date_of_Birth.Value)
    DOBDay = Day(Date_of_Birth.Value)
    DOBYear = Year(Date_of_Birth.Value)

    If DOBMonth < 10 Then
        Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("BirthDate").setattribute("value", "0" & DOBMonth & "/" & DOBDay & "/" & DOBYear)
    Else
        Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("BirthDate").setattribute("value", DOBMonth & "/" & DOBDay & "/" & DOBYear)
    End If
Call IE.Document.getelementbyid("StNumber").setattribute("value", Street_Number.Value)

'"clicks" the button to display the results
IE.Document.getelementbyid("ButtonForm").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML snippet you provided belongs to iframe `<iframe id="dnn_ctr1579_View_VoterLookupFrame" src="https://www.electionsfl.org/VoterInfo/vflookup.html?county=lee" width="100%" height="2000" frameborder="0"></iframe>`, so you should navigate to URL https://www.electionsfl.org/VoterInfo/vflookup.html?county=lee instead of http://www.lee.vote/voters/check-your-registration-status/.

I navigated https://www.electionsfl.org/VoterInfo/vflookup.html?county=lee in Chrome and checked XHR logged after I submit the data via Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), Network tab:

[image: xhr]

Seems that is simple POST XML HTTP request with payload in JSON format, like:

```json
{'LastName':'Doe', 'BirthDate':'01/01/1980', 'StNumber':'10025', 'County':'lee', 'FirstName':'', 'challengeValue':'', 'responseValue':''}
```

That XHR uses no cookies or any other authorization data neither in headers nor payload, so I tried to reproduce the same request using the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Submit_VoterInfo()

    Dim sLastName As String
    Dim sBirthDate As String
    Dim sStNumber As String
    Dim sFormData As String
    Dim bytFormData
    Dim sContent As String

    ' Put the necessary data here
    sLastName = "Doe"
    sBirthDate = "01/01/1980"
    sStNumber = "10025"
    ' Combine form payload
    sFormData = "{" & _
    "'LastName':'" & sLastName & "', " & _
    "'BirthDate':'" & sBirthDate & "', " & _
    "'StNumber':'" & sStNumber & "', " & _
    "'County':'lee', " & _
    "'FirstName':'', " & _
    "'challengeValue':'', " & _
    "'responseValue':''" & _
    "}"
    ' Convert string to UTF-8 binary
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .WriteText sFormData
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        .Position = 3 ' skip BOM
        bytFormData = .Read
        .Close
    End With
    ' Make POST XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://www.electionsfl.org/VoterInfo/asmx/service1.asmx/FindVoter", False, "u051772", "mar4fy16"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", LenB(bytFormData)
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        .Send bytFormData
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    ' Show response
    Debug.Print sContent

End Sub
```

The response for me is `{"d":"[]"}`, the same as in browser, but unfortunately I can't check if it processed on the server correctly, since I have no valid voter record data.

Comment: That didn't work.  It didn't return any error message, but it didn't seem to interact with the webpage either.